# When was the word "trinity" first applied to God in Christianity?

Tags: trinity, church-history, church-fathers, origin

The word "trinity" does not occur in the Bible.

When, in early Christian writings and creeds, was the word "trinity" first used in reference to God?

After that first (known) occurrence, what are some of the other key earliest uses of the word "trinity" in reference to God in Christian writings and creeds?

*(Please do not respond with general defenses of the doctrine of the Trinity. This is a doctrinal history question specifically about the earliest uses of the word "trinity" in relation to God.)*

Comment: This question parallels my earlier question, [When in the development of trinitarian doctrine was the word “persons” first applied to God?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39816/when-in-the-development-of-trinitarian-doctrine-was-the-word-persons-first-app)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without question, [Theophilus of Antioch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophilus_of_Antioch) (d. 183) is your man. He wrote in Greek:

> [God's creations on the first three days--light, sky, and vegetation--] are types of the Trinity [[Τριάδος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3D%23104807&redirect=true)], of God, and His Word, and His wisdom. And the fourth [day, the creation of the moon and stars,] is the type of man, who needs light, that so there may be God, the Word, wisdom, man.
>
> *[Theophilus to Autolycus](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Fathers/Volume_II/Theophilus_to_Autolycus)*, [Book II](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Fathers/Volume_II/Theophilus_to_Autolycus/Book_II)

You often hear [Tertullian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertullian)'s (155 - 240) name in connection with this, but he was the first *Latin* writer to use the term ([trinitas](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtrinitas) in his case), as well as the [first to connect it with the word "persons."](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39816/when-in-the-development-of-trinitarian-doctrine-was-the-word-persons-first-app/40023#40023)

Comment: See also [III. THE DOCTRINE OF THE HOLY SPIRIT IN JUSTIN AND IRENÆUS](http://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/03d/0130-0202,_Iraeneus,_Demonstration_Of_The_Apostolic_Preaching,_EN.pdf) in the exquisite introduction to _The Demonstration of the Apostolic Preaching_, which discusses the contemporary works of Theophilus, Justin Martyr, and Irenaeus. Specifically, the author on p. 31 cites the above. As a whole, that document is very informative about the time and nature of the development of that doctrine within Christianity.