# Earliest use of the term triune

Tags: trinity, terminology, greek, latin

According to [dictionary.com, the origin of the term triune](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/triune) was between:

> 1595–1605; tri- + -une < Latin ūnus one

What are some of the earliest uses of the English *triune*, as well as it's Latin and Greek (if such exist) equivalents?

Comment: What constitutes a Greek or Latin equivalent? Is Τριάδος equivalent? It would typically be translated as Trinity.

Comment: @bradimus I'm not really sure there is a Greek equivalent. Google says it's τρισυπόστατος. I don't know anything about Latin but I assume it's triūnus.

Comment: Since you are looking for the earliest use of specific words rather than the theological concept attached to the word, you might get better answers at https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Most straight forward etymology questions get shot down pretty quickly on ELU.  You're asking about the adjective, but I take it that you've already seen the question about the noun: [When was the word “trinity” first applied to God in Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/40025/21576)

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes I would like to know about the adjective. I was surprised to see that's it's a fairly new word. I know it means the same thing as trinity, but sometimes theology can make adjectives mean brand new things. Should I ask about when triune was first used specifically towards the triune god, or is my question okay as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *OED* gives this as the earliest English usage of the term "[triune](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/206513)":

> <sup>1605   T. Tymme tr. J. Du Chesne *Pract. Chymicall & Hermeticall Physicke* ii. ii. 108</sup>
>    It hath pleased the omnipotent Creator to..showe himself a Unitrine or Triune.

According to the [*Index Thomisticus*](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age), *triunus* (or any of its forms) is not found in the works of St. Thomas Aquinas, so the Latin term *triunus* is probably more recent than the 13<sup>th</sup> century.

Comment: Thanks Geremia, I don't have access to that encyclopedia so this helps a lot. I wonder why Unitrine never took off.

Comment: @anonymouswho The _OED_ says "unitrine" is obsolete, and it gives only the Tymme quote above illustrating the usage of "unitrine". There are several quotes given for "triune".