# Where do Christians believe the Qur'an came from?

Tags: islam, creeds-and-confessions, special-revelation

The "prophet" Muhammad stated that the angel Gabriel visited him with revelation and he put great importance upon Gabriel.

So my question is, where do Christians believe Muhammad's revelation came from and what Christians believe about Muhammad's claim about his revelations from Gabriel? Do they believe that he lied and made it up, or do they believe it was a demon rather than Gabriel who visited Muhammad?

The question is seeking answers based on doctrinal and official views of any Christian denominations.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to take issue with this question.  This isn't a question about Christianity.  It is a question about those who practice Christianity - which is not a unified group with single representation.  In a similar regard, if you ask a question on Islam.SE about Muslims, it will be off topic as it is not a question about the faith but those who apply it.  Such as, "[Why do some Muslims use the moon and star](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1245)" - my question was NOT an Islamic question but a Muslim question

Comment: [Is the Qur'an compatible with Christianity?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3512)

Comment: From a dude who made it up, the used it to take over the known world, and nearly succeeded, by the way. Is there any other possible answer? There might be a few wishy-washy churches that take the name Christian and also regard the Quran with some esteem, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Which Christians? There's no universal "Christian" belief about Islam, or it's history.

Comment: I believe *davidbrainerd's* [answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32336/where-do-christians-believe-the-quran-came-from/32337#32337) can be supported from [Koran | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08692a.htm) (see: Sources) and [my answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32336/where-do-christians-believe-the-quran-came-from/32340#32340) is extremely well-supported (Catholic/Christian creed; Scripture; 2 Popes, Catholic saints and authors, etc.). Not my question, so let *eliyah* fight for his question.

Comment: just wanted to know of any established denominational stance toward its source (the Quran), wether it was believed to be from the mind of a man or if they believe it was from direct contact with the devil or a demon whom muhammad (decieved) mistook for the angel Gabriel.

Comment: @eliyah From the Catholic sources in my answer, the inspiration behind the Koran, is NOT from God. Some say it his Muhammad's own invention and others that it is a diabolical inspiration and each provide their reasoning. All clearly state that it is contradictory to Christianity, with some of those leaving the reader to draw their own conclusion.

Comment: *Which Christians? There's no universal "Christian" belief about Islam, or it's history.* **Response:** When Islam + Qur'an sprang up, Catholicism was on the scene and had something to say about it. Unless the other Christians when they came to be repudiated  the Catholic position or they themselves made a statement on Islam + Qur'an, it appears it is only Catholics/Catholicism that has said something about Islam + Qur'an. There aren't any other Christian views out there on Islam + Qur'an.

Comment: @FMShyanguya, very interresting , Im surprised that no denominations have made a official view other than just rejecting Islam.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32639/apart-from-catholics-catholicism-what-have-other-ecclesial-communities-christia).

Answer (score 14):

> The "prophet" Muhammad stated that the angel Gabriel visited him with revelation and he put great importance upon Gabriel.

*This is not true.*  Not if you are talking about the Koran, which never says this.  This information comes from the Hadiths.  If you were to base your understanding of Mohammed purely on his writings (i.e. the Koran) and not on the hearsay stories of later Muslim tradition, you would not come to the conclusion that Mohammed said anything about Gabriel.

The way Mohammed presents it in the Koran, it sounds like he's claiming Allah himself is speaking to him. There is no specific mention of Gabriel doing anything with revelation, other than in Sura 2:97-98 which is easy to miss. In fact, Michael is mentioned in the same context. Nowhere in the Koran does Mohammed specifically claim that any of his "revelation" comes from Gabriel. This specific place seems to be making Gabriel "confirm" the message (similarly to the Holy Spirit in Christianity) and that anyone who rejects revelation is an enemy of Gabriel and Michael and all the angels.

In point of fact, Sura 2:98 doesn't even specifically call Gabriel and Michael angels, but may even intend them to be *human messengers*, for it says "Whoever is the enemy of Allah and His angels and His messengers and Jibreel and Meekaeel, so surely Allah is the enemy of the unbelievers."  It could even be taken that Gabriel and Michael are being placed in a third category all their own, and not among the angels nor the messengers.  This would not be surprising considering the *very low* state of Mohammed's biblical knowledge (to be discussed below).

A reading of Mohammed's book (i.e. the Koran) will show that he pieced his "revelation" together from Bible stories that he *heard* taught (he obviously didn't read the Bible) and from stories and legends taken from the Talmud which he *heard* (e.g. the angels being commanded to worship Adam) and from Pagan stories which he *heard* (e.g. "God's own she-camel").

That he did not receive his information from any angel nor from actually reading the Bible is clear from how he mangles Bible stories, like getting Haman from the book of Esther into the story of Moses, and making Haman the builder of the tower of Babel, in Moses' day, by having Pharaoh say to Haman "Build me a tower so I can climb to heaven and see Moses' God." (Koran, in Sura 28:38 and Sura 40:36-37)

The Koran also confuses Mary the mother of Jesus with Miriam the sister of Moses, explicitly calling Mary "the daughter of Amram" (or Imram) and "sister of Aaron" several times.  Its pretty clear that Mohammed *has no sense of chronology*, and thinks that Jesus was Moses' nephew and received the *Injeel* (Gospel) not long after Moses received the *Tavrat* (Torah), perhaps only a decade or so later.

This kind of mixing up of various biblical stories into one can only occur as a result of being illiterate, of not having read the Bible, and of accidentally mixing up stories you heard in your head. It would be hard to completely lack a sense of chronology if you had actually read the Bible.  Surely nobody would mix up stories this badly on purpose. And surely no angel would be malevolent enough to play a dirty trick like this on anyone, or at least Gabriel would not.

Edit: In response to comments citing particular verses of the Koran which supposedly give Gabriel a more prominent place than I've suggested above.  We must remember that the Koran is not like the Bible.  You can't just translate the Koran with a formal-equivalence type translational methodology, because it will come out as ungrammatical jibberish.  Muslims admit as much by teaching that "the Koran in untranslatable" and therefore they claim that to really read the Koran you must read it in Arabic.  Contrary to this, the KJV translators write in their preface that even the "meanest" (i.e. roughest) translation of the Bible is still the word of God.  The reason is we don't have to supplement a bunch of tradition and stuff from other sources to even end up with a grammatical sentence when translating the Bible. But with the Koran, you pretty much do.  So without Islamic tradition and all the details that it adds about Gabriel and so on, it would be very hard to produce a translation of the Koran that's even barely readable. If you were, however, to attempt to wade through a literal, formal-equivalence, translation of the Koran, you would find all this stuff about Gabriel and several other things to be missing.  This is another proof, in my estimation, that the Koran does not come from any kind of supernatural source, neither from God or any angel, nor from Satan or any demon, but merely from the mind of a man.

Comment: indeed, thanks great answer brother. I only took in the hole Gabriel concept because I was given a Quran for free and at the begining of the Quran it mentioned how Gabriel visited him and how afterwards he fell down exhausted and his wife ( if im not mistaken) tended to him when she found him. Also upon the basis that many muslims have told me that they refer to Gabriel as the holy spirit contrary to the Christian concept of the holy spirit.

Comment: so in conclusion you believe that it was not from a demon but instead it was conjured up in his mind from a shaky memory? so wouldnt that make him a liar for claiming to be a prophet?

Comment: @eliyah, More or less. I think he had psychological experiences that convinced him he was a prophet, and he combined these feelings with a shaky knowledge of Christianity and Judaism and a few stories from some Pagan monotheists.

Comment: @ david brainerd, ok I see, makes sense, he possibly thought that he was a prophet and that he was doing right, wow entire empires with this as a foundation ( shaking my head).

Comment: Which *Christian denomination view* is this?

Comment: *There is no specific mention of Gabriel doing anything with revelation* Not true as S. 2:97 has: **Say, "Whoever is an enemy to Gabriel - it is [none but] he who has brought the Qur'an down upon your heart, [O Muhammad], by permission of Allah , confirming that which was before it and as guidance and good tidings for the believers."** cf. [S. 2:97-98](http://quran.com/2/97-98)

Comment: Well said......

Comment: @FMShyanguya, thank you for confirming the importance of Gabriel here, I was not exactly sure where else Gabriel was mentioned in the Quran, thanks again.

Comment: @davidbrainerd. I must point out to you Sura 81: 19 - 21. I think your answer is wrong as regards the claim that Gabriel brought the message - it is definitely part of the Koran.

Comment: @gideon marx, Gabriel is not specifically mentioned in Sura 81:19-21.  Some translations inject his name there from Muslim tradition. Its paraphrase. Look at several different translations and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @gideon marx, See also Sura 81:23, where some translations give the literal "He saw him at the high horizon" (saw who?) And the paraphrases say "And he has already seen Gabriel in the clear horizon." So whether you see Gabriel there or not depends on whether you are reading a literal formal-equivalence translation or a dogmatic translation that changes the Koran to fit later Muslim tradition.

Comment: @davidbrainerd. The Islamic scholarly commentary in my Koran gives a reasonable sounding explanation for imposing oral tradition on scripture. As they are the experts, I have to accept their view. One cannot tell them what to believe. The Crusaders killed Jews and Muslims to get to heaven. Muslims today kill Christians and Jews to get to heaven. Is it right according to the letter of the Bible or Koran? Does it matter in the slightest to the dead? Listen to what Islam says is in the Koran. They are the ones willing to wield the knives.

Comment: @gideon marx, I'm not telling them what to believe.  The question approached it from a Christian perspective. It makes sense that from such a perspective we would ignore Muslim tradition and judge the Koran based on its actual words, translated with a literal methodology. Especially since the question is not what Muslims believe but where do we believe Mohammed got his "revelation."

Comment: I'm down voting this because it's not friendly to the Muslim reader and does not convey compassion to their current situation.

Comment: @gideonmarx In response to your remarks, pls see:  [Was the justification for the crusades different from the justification of “Jihad”? - on hold](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32451/was-the-justification-for-the-crusades-different-from-the-justification-of-jiha).

Answer (score 8):

**Answering**

If the Christian Revelation and the revelation of Islam are both from God, then there is a problem.
*(see below)*

---

*"[I]t is proper to the devil to mix falsehood with truth[.]"* - in *Catena Aurea* | St. John Chrysostom

---

Compare the Islamic and [the beginning of] the Christian creeds:

> The [*Shahada*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) [The Islamic creed]:
>   لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّااللهمُحَمَّدٌرَسُولُالله | *lā ʾilāha ʾil ʾāllāh,
>   muḥammadun rasūlu-llāh* | **“There is no god but Allah, Muhammad is
>   the messenger of Allah [God].”**

vs.

> Jn 17:3: And eternal life is this: **to know you, the only true God,
>   and Jesus Christ whom you have sent**. [I believe in God, the Father
>   almighty creator of heaven and earth, and in Jesus Christ, his only
>   Son, our LORD, [...] | [The Apostles’ Creed](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01629a.htm)]

The two [creeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creed) [key word in definition: **core**] are irreconcilable; therefore both religions cannot be true.

If one of them is the true Faith, the other is a corruption of it and therefore not true.

---

> It is hardly surprising, then, that throughout history the adversary
>   establishes false religions, sects, and cults in which he masquerades
>   as God. Frequently, these cults spring forth from the bosom of real
>   religion; consider the recent instance[s] of David Koresh and his Waco
>   cult, [...] which pretended to be Christian and made continual
>   reference to the Bible.
>
> Of all the major religions of the world, only Islam arose after God's
>   full revelation of Himself to man in His incarnation in the person of
>   Jesus Christ. Thus all of the other major religions are either fully
>   true (Christianity); fully true up to the time of their origin, but
>   lacking the later revelation (Judaism); or based on the incomplete
>   revelations available to mankind before God chose to make Himself
>   truly known. **Only Islam's revelation came after Christ, aware of
>   Christianity yet contradicting it. Hence one must ask what the  source
>   of the revelation was-was it of human or of supernatural origin? If of
>   supernatural origin, did it come from God or from fallen spirits? It
>   is difficult for a Christian to  consider the source of the revelation
>   to be God, given its contradictions with Christian revelation.** -
>   Excerpt from *Salvation is from the Jews | Roy Schoeman*, a Jew who
>   has come to the fullness of his faith in the Catholic Church.

---

Further reading:

- [What Did the Saints Say about Islam? | ANDREW BIESZAD ON    1P5, August 12, 2014](http://www.onepeterfive.com/what-did-the-saints-say-about-islam/).

> “There is also the superstition of the Ishmaelites which to this day
>   prevails and keeps people in error, being a forerunner of the
>   Antichrist…. From that time to the present a false prophet named
>   Mohammed has appeared in their midst. This man, after having chanced
>   upon the Old and New Testaments and likewise, it seems, having
>   conversed with an Arian monk, devised his own heresy. Then, having
>   insinuated himself into the good graces of the people by a show of
>   seeming piety, he gave out that a certain book had been sent down to
>   him from heaven. He had set down some ridiculous compositions in this
>   book of his and he gave it to them as an object of veneration.”
>
> -*St. John Damascene* (d. 749), Syrian Arab Catholic monk and scholar. Quoted from his book On Heresies under the section On the Heresy of
>   the Ishmaelites (in The Fathers of the Church. Vol. 37. Translated by
>   the Catholic University of America. CUA Press. 1958. Pages 153-160.)

- [Lecture of the Holy Father Pope Emeritus Benedict XVI | Aula Magna of the University of Regensburg, Tuesday, 12 September 2006](http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/benedict_xvi/speeches/2006/september/documents/hf_ben-xvi_spe_20060912_university-regensburg_en.html).
- This [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/is-the-quran-compatible-with-christianity/31187#31187) to *Is the Qur'an compatible with Christianity?*
- [The Great and Enduring Heresy (sic) of Mohammed | THE GREAT HERESIES, Chapter Four |  by Hilaire Belloc | EWTN](http://www.ewtn.com/library/homelibr/heresy4.txt).
- [Christianity and Islam: A Common Heritage? | WILLIAM KILPATRICK | Crisis Magazine](http://www.crisismagazine.com/2014/common-heritage).

---

*On the nature of Muhammad's prophetic experience*

- [B. MUHAMMAD'S CONCEPT OF REVELATION. | The Nature of Muhammad's Prophetic Experience | Answering Islam](http://answering-islam.org/Gilchrist/Vol1/3b.html).

> The best proof of the reality of Mohammed's belief in the reality of
>   the revelation, and of the completeness of his sincerity, is that he
>   fell at the first into a state of doubt concerning it. (Gairdner, *The
>   Reproach of Islam,* p. 46).
>
> This openly-expressed doubt about the source of the revelations
>   strengthens all the more the suggestion that Muhammad really did see
>   these two visions which took him somewhat by surprise. Nevertheless it
>   is very interesting to find that Muhammad initially believed that
>   these manifestations were probably demonic.
>
> **Therefore Muhammad really did see something. What is it then that he saw? That's the question.**
>
> *2. The Exoteric Character of the Revelations.*
>
> Although the visions ceased, it is recorded that the revelations of
>   Qur'anic passages were invariably attested by outward, physical
>   phenomena. Ayishah reported:
>
> Verily, al-Harith Ibn Hisham said: O Apostle of Allah! how does
>   revelation dawn upon you? The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him,
>   said: Sometimes it dawns upon me in the form of the ringing of a bell,
>   and that is very hard on me; (ultimately) it ceases and I remember
>   what is said. Sometimes the angel appears to me and speaks and I
>   recollect what he says. Ayishah said: I witnessed the revelation
>   dawning upon him on an extremely cold day; when it ceased, I noticed
>   that his forehead was perspiring. (Ibn Sa'd, *Kitab al-Tabaqat
>   al-Kabir,* Vol. 1, p. 228).
>
> The other major traditions all say that the angel, when it appeared to
>   Muhammad, did so in human form, though in the Qur'an we have already
>   seen how strongly Muhammad claimed to have seen the angel only on the
>   two specific occasions it mentions and the testimony of the Qur'an is
>   more reliable than that of the Hadith. Another tradition says:
>
> Ubada b. Samit reported that when wahi descended upon Allah's Apostle
>   (may peace be upon him), he felt a burden on that account and the
>   colour of his face underwent a change. (*Sahih Muslim,* Vol. 4, p.
>   1248).

Comment: so would you say its from fallen angels/ demons?

Comment: @eliyah Affirmative, and thank you for continuing to ask great questions!

Comment: "There is no god but Allah, Muhammad is the messenger of Allah" - is actually understood as "There is no god but Allah, Muhammad is the [**LAST**] messenger of Allah" as Jesus is also a messenger in Islam (and born of a virgin, and a healer, and rose into heaven)

Comment: @TheFreemason The creeds are compared from how they are recited and not how they are understood. Even with the understanding you present, one is still left with the Christian side that does not accept Muhammad as the messenger of God, let alone his last messenger.

Comment: @FMShyanguya agreed and why would Christianity since Islam came after Christianity started.  It's like saying, "why doesn't the bible talk about the internet?"

Comment: @TheFreemason We accept, venerate, and honor the saints and prophets and teachers in the Church that have come after Jesus' life, death and resurrection. Muhhammad is not one of them.

Comment: Can you name a prophet after Jesus?  Either way, we're splitting hairs here.  Enjoy!

Comment: @TheFreemason [Benedict XVI: Pope as Prophet](http://www.crisismagazine.com/2014/pope-as-prophet) & [Ac 13:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+13%3A1&version=RSVCE), and all [the baptised](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a1.htm#1268).

Answer (score 3):

As David points out, the Qur'an itself doesn't testify that Muhammad received his revelation from Gabriel. In fact, when Muhammad first received his 'revelation', he believed he was possessed, and attempted to hurl himself off a cliff (Ibn Ishaq, p. 106). It wasn't until talking with his wife Khadija that she gave him the idea he wasn't possessed but was a prophet.

I'd like to mention one other incident, Muhammad himself claimed at least one of his revelation came from Satan;

While Muhammad was in Mecca, his followers were few, his movement grew painfully slowly and he, too, felt the pain of estrangement from his tribe. According to early and treasured biographical and historical accounts of Muhammad, authored by competent Muslim scholars (such as writings of at-Tabari and Ibn Sa’d), Muhammad longed for better relations and reconciliation with his community. Thereafter, the accounts continue, God revealed Surah 53 to Muhammad up to and including vss. 19, 20. These two verses read:

> Have ye thought upon al-Lat and al-Uzza
>   And Manat, the third, the other? (53:19,20)

Then, originally, the verses (known today as the satanic verses) followed:

> These are the exalted cranes (intermediaries)
>   Whose intercession is to be hoped for.

The cranes whose intercession was recognized were, of course, the three deities. The same accounts tell us that after this revelation was completed, Muhammad, his followers and the pagan Arabs all prostrated. Tensions eased, reconciliation was at hand, and all were delighted.

But Muhammad soon retracted the reconciliation—how soon is not clear. For the account continues that Jibril (Gabriel), the angel of revelation, informed Muhammad that Satan had used Muhammad's desire for reconciliation with the pagan leaders to insert into the revelation of God the verses about the interceding cranes, otherwise called "the satanic verses".

To summarize, Muhammad originally believed he was demon-possessed and attempted suicide, later Muhammad gives a revelation promoting polytheism, then retracts it claiming Satan gave him the revelation.

Comment: This is a good description of where Muhammad believed his revelations came from; but it doesn't seem to answer the question of where Christians believe it came from.

Comment: wow great answer my friend! jaw dropping infact, your answer was very rewarding and praise worthy, bless you child of God, thanks again for that answer.

Comment: *As David points out, the Qur'an itself doesn't testify that Muhammad received his revelation from Gabriel.* Not true, davidbrainerd has edited his answer.

Comment: I agree with Matt, this doesn't answer the question or extend David's answer so that it does answer the question.